# mysqli query join with two unique key

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello all i am having this query in my webpage

```
 $otherupdates=mysqli_query
($conn,"
    SELECT f.sender,f.receiver,f.field,m.name 
    FROM friend f,members m
    WHERE ((f.sender IN ($variable) OR f.receiver IN ($variable)) 
    AND ( f.field='friends' || f.field='fan') 
    AND ( f.date > '$adatevariable' AND f.sender=m.id)) 
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 16"
);

$variable="'1','2','3'......"; // not important
$adatevariable=date('d', strtotime($today . ' - 2 day'));// not imp
```

what this query does is, fetches all the rows which matches the where clause and also fetches the name of sender (f.sender=m.id) but i want the name of receiver too by this query only i do not need another query..

is this possible please help

Comment: can you please provide more details such as db structure and expected result, you may need to use a join clause tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your query to be:

```
select 
    f.sender,
    f.receiver,
    f.field,
    senders.name AS sender_name,
    recievers.name AS recievers_name
from 
    friend f
    INNER JOIN members senders ON f.sender=senders.id
    INNER JOIN members recievers ON f.receiver = recievers.id
where 
    (f.sender IN ($variable) or f.receiver IN ($variable)) 
    and f.field IN ('friends', 'fan') 
    and f.date > '$adatevariable'
order by 
    date desc 
limit 16
```

What this does is allow you to access the `members` table twice, once as `senders` and again as `recievers`. By joining these to your `friend` table on the `sender` and `reciever` fields, `senders` will have all the information of the sender and `recievers` will have all the information on the reciever.

Comment: sir, the query is showing the same name for sender as well as receiver !!

Comment: sender_name and recievers_name is same despite of different  sender and receiver and their id in members table

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your data as this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2245/4) shows that you do get different values for sender and reciever.